# how to configure npm artifactory authentication in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, artifactory

I didn't find any way to configure jfrog artifactory login credentials in node project package.json
Here is a sample JSON way to configure for **PHP composer.json**

```
{
  "config": {
    "http-basic": {
      "artifacts.jfrog.io":{
        "username": "usernamexxxxxx",
        "password": "passwordxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  },
  "repositories":{
    "type": "composer"
    "url": "https://artifcts.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/composer/php-release-virtual"
  }
}
```

Can we configure it like this for **node project package.json**

Comment: `npm login`? See https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/npm+Registry (Authenticating the npm Client)

Comment: Hi, @ChrLipp Can't we set it in package.json?